# Can't grok a haskell type signature "instance Misty ((->) t "

Tags: haskell, types

I just read Learn you a haskell, liked what I saw so started playing with the language. I found some exercise online that I'be been working to get type checking.

My problem is I don't understand what (->) is in the type signature Misty ((->) t below.

```
class Misty m where
   banana :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
   unicorn :: a -> m a

 --- what does this mean?
 instance Misty ((->) t) where
   banana = error "todo" 
   unicorn = error "todo"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just replace `(m a)` with `(t -> a)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`((->) t)` is a function with an argument type of `t`, for example the functor instance of `(->) r` looks like:

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where
    fmap = (.)
```

Since the type of `fmap` is

```
Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

and the type of `(.)` is

```
(a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> c)
```

you can see that `f` is a function with an argument type `r`.

In your `Misty` class this means the type of `banana` and `unicorn` are:

```
banana :: (a -> (t -> b)) -> (t -> a) -> (t -> b)
unicorn :: (a -> (t -> a))
```

Answer (score 3):

Any type `(a -> b)` can be rewritten as `(->) a b`.

`(->) a` is just a partial application!

So, you are actually going to make a function `((->) a)` an instance of `Misty`.

Comment: So, is the exercise looking for something that, given a function that takes A's and returns Misty B's, returns a function from Misty A's to Misty B's? That makes sense, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around what it means in the context of this example

Comment: When you have trouble understanding, just write out the specialized type for your typeclass function: `banana :: (a -> (t -> b)) -> (t -> a) -> (t -> b)`. Now try to think over this, it will be much easier.